# Reset a form in AngularJS from HTML or in-built directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have a common `form` (having set of *`input` fields*, a *`submit` button*, a *cancel button* and a *close-icon*) inside bootstrap modal popup. When one clicks on the name which is being iterated using the Object data-list through `ng-repeat`, the popup (containing the form) opens up.

I have the following scenarios:

- One can validate the `input` fields (by entering valid entries) and then clicking the Submit button. *No Issues*
- One can either click the Cancel button or the close icon without entering any value in the `input` fields. *No Issues*
- One can enter *invalid* entries in the `input` fields and then click Submit. *I have handled this.*
- One can enter the *invalid* entries and then click on Cancel or close icon. **This is the issue.**

> The last scenario illustrates the **issue**:

When one clicks on the first DOM of the `ng-repeat`, the `form` loads. The user closes the popup modal when the `form` is *invalid*.

When the `form` is again opened, the `form` **doesn't** gets reset. I am using `controller as` in the project and **cannot** use `$scope`.

I know, one can reset the `form`, from the `controller` using the following syntax:

```
$scope.formName.$setPristine();
```

I need to do it from the HTML itself using the built in *directives* like `ng-init` or any other.

**EDIT 1:**

As per request, I have added the code and the sample [link](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/0k496jyd/).

*Note:* In the sample, on clicking the *Submit* button in the popup, the error gets displayed, for the `input` fields that are *invalid*.

> **Expected:**

*On closing the popup, after opening it for the First time (keeping the form invalid) and then opening it up again, the error shouldn't get displayed unless the fields are invalid and Submit button is clicked.*

> **Actual:**

*On opening the popup for the second time, the error beneath the invalid input fields does gets displayed.*

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="test as ctrl">
  <h4 class="lead" align="center">
Popup Display
</h4>
  <div class="row">
    <div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.dataList" class="col-xs-6 form-group" align="center">
      <div class="img-thumbnail pointer" ng-click="ctrl.openPopup(item)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#testPopup" data-backdrop="static">
        <span>{{item.name}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div id="testPopup" role="dialog" class="popup-modal-section modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form name="inputForm.form" novalidate ng-submit="ctrl.saveData(inputForm.form.$valid, ctrl.selected);">
            <h3 class="lead" align="center">
Profile Details:
</h3>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div>
                <label>Name</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="ctrl.selected.name" name="name" ng-required="true" />
                <span class="error" ng-show="(inputForm.form.name.$error.required || inputForm.form.name.$invalid)">Name is required</span>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <div>
                <label>City</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="ctrl.selected.city" name="city" ng-required="true" />
                <span class="error" ng-show="(inputForm.form.city.$touched &&  inputForm.form.city.$error.required) || (inputForm.form.$submitted &&     inputForm.form.city.$error.required)">City is required</span>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div align="right">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                Submit
              </button>
              <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                Close
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('test', function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.dataList = [{
    "id": "0",
    "name": "Pankaj M."
  }, {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Rakesh G."
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Piyush C."
  }, {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Danny K."
  }];

  vm.openPopup = function(data) {
    vm.selected = angular.copy(data);
  };

  vm.saveData = function(isValid, data) {
    console.log('Form Valid ', isValid);
  };
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.error {
  color: red;
}
```

Refer to the demo [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/0k496jyd/)

Comment: if the form is bound to a specific state... then you can call a state reload.

Comment: Post your code, how you set up modal. You can do it of course, but likely that you are opening it wrong in the first place.

Comment: @Hitmands, can u explain how?

Comment: @dfsq, I have posted the code, can you have a look now?

Comment: Yes, you are doing it wrong as I said. The problem is that you work with Twitter bootstrap. I recommend using UI Bootstrap $modal service.

Comment: @dfsq, yeah...but isn't der any oder way to reset the bootstrap modal?

Comment: Check the answer I posted. This is proper way to do it. You should not use Twitter Bootstrap and jQuery in Angular app. This is one of the problems (not the only) you are going to deal with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you work with Twitter Bootstrap modal, and what happens is that it uses the same HTML template for all modal instances. You don't want this.

Proper approach would be to remove Twitter Bootstrap (and jQuery) - you don't need it. Instead you would use dedicated Angular directive. I suggest [UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) $modal service.

Then it would become cleaner and more Angular rather than jQuery.

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('test', function($uibModal) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.dataList = [{
    "id": "0",
    "name": "Pankaj M."
  }, {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Rakesh G."
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Piyush C."
  }, {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Danny K."
  }];

  vm.openPopup = function(data) {
    $uibModal.open({
      bindToController: true,
      controllerAs: 'ctrl',
      templateUrl: 'profile.html',
      resolve: {
        user: angular.copy(data)
      },
      controller: function(user) {
        this.selected = user;
      }
    }).result
    .then(function(updated) {
      vm.saveData(data, updated);
    })
  };

  vm.saveData = function(data, updated) {
    angular.extend(data, updated);
    console.log('Form Valid', data);
  };
});
```

modal HTML:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <form name="inputForm.form" novalidate="" ng-submit="inputForm.form.$valid && $close(ctrl.selected)">
    <h3 class="lead text-center">Profile Details:</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div>
        <label>Name</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="ctrl.selected.name" name="name" ng-required="true" />
        <span class="error" ng-show="(inputForm.form.name.$error.required || inputForm.form.name.$invalid)">Name is required</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div>
        <label>City</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="ctrl.selected.city" name="city" ng-required="true" />
        <span class="error" ng-show="(inputForm.form.city.$touched &&  inputForm.form.city.$error.required) || (inputForm.form.$submitted && inputForm.form.city.$error.required)">City is required</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div align="right">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="$dismiss()">Close</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/NuOWdDHzDiN2hszB5u4P?p=info

Comment: Not at all, make this change now instead of going into totally wrong direction. Otherwise you are risking creating pretty low-quality app, that is hard to maintain. Remember jQuery is not needed and often pretty harmful in Angular app.

Answer (score 0):

As per your description there can be form scope issue. So you can pass your form in submit or close function and then call pristine in that. Like this :

```
$scope.submit=function(form){
  form.$setPristine();
}
```

Or to avoid this issue you can create one object in your controller and then assin form as the porperty that object. Like this

```
$scope.formObject={};
```

And in html use dot expression for form name like this:

```
<form name="formObject.test_form">
 ...
</form>
```

It would be more better if you can post your code

Comment: *"And in html use dot expression for form name"* - why?

Comment: If you are not using dot expression in you code in angular js then you might be doing something wrong. When you create object in controller , then on page the variable will be used from controller, but if the page variable is not found in controller, then it might create separate scope variable for that. http://zcourts.com/2013/05/31/angularjs-if-you-dont-have-a-dot-youre-doing-it-wrong/#sthash.J64oexPf.dpbs

Comment: No, of course I know this stuff. I'm misunderstood you. Anyway, i don't see how it would solve OP's issue, seems that all form instances are bound to the same object, so it won't work I guess.

Comment: i faced this kind of issue. But Yes i am also not sure about exact problem in OP's code, as there is not much code in question

Comment: I have added the code and link. Can you have a look at it now and get it to the point?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in many ways:

1. create a reset method for your form model and call it when your modal gets closed:

```js
function TestCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.initModel = function() {
    $scope.fields = {
      "something": "INITIAL VALUE"
    };
  };
  
  $scope.initModel();
}
angular
  .module('test', [])
  .controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', TestCtrl])
;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<section ng-app="test">
  <article ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <form name="test" ng-submit="onSubmit($event, test)">
      <input ng-model="fields.something" type="text" />
    </form>
  </article>
</section>
```

2. Create a specific application state for that form, doing that you're able to call a $location change and re-instantiate each bound controller (an example would be too long, but, if you need I'll go to do it).

Comment: I have updated the answer with the code. Can you do it with minimal changes i.e. without adding any other dependency like `$location`, etc.? I don't think the first one will solve my case, as on every click I am fetching the object from the list.